# How do I validate ribbon buttons based on the type of user in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 13 buttons that can be used by one user (Teacher), of those another type of user (Student) can use 9.

I tried this:

```vb
Sub GetEnabled(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef enabled)
  Select Case control.ID
    Case "Button2"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button3"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button4"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button5"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button6"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button7"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button8"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button10"
      enabled = Not (estado)
    Case "Button11"
      enabled = Not (estado)
  End Select
End Sub

Sub OnActionButton(control As IRibbonControl)
  Select Case control.ID  
    Case "Button2"
      estado = Not (estado)
      CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button3"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button4"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button5"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button6"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button7"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button8"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button10"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
    Case "Button11"
      estado = Not (estado)
       CintaOpciones.Invalidate
  End Select
End Sub
```

That code is supposed to disable the buttons that the student user cannot use.

In the code XML I have:
Just that little bit like for example

```
<button id="Button2" label="Crear Grupo" image="agregar-grupo" onAction="Ribbon.CrearGrupo" getEnabled = GetEnabled/>
                <button id="Button3" label="Asignar Clave" image="clave" onAction="Ribbon.claveModulos" getEnabled = GetEnabled/>
```

In the form Login I validate if user student then call function, but I don't know what to put there.

Comment: What did you try by yourself? What does "type of user" mean in this context? Using the `UserName` and make selection only based on that,  shouldn't be enough? Then, VBA code can be seen, by a user being comfortable with Visual Basic for Applications, even if you try protecting the VBAProject. What you really want accomplishing, in fact?

Comment: Thanks, I already edited it

Answer (score 0):

You are missing double quotes around the `GetEnabled` attribute.

```
<button id="Button3" label="Asignar Clave" image="clave" onAction="Ribbon.claveModulos" getEnabled="GetEnabled"/>
```

Here is na excellent resuorce from Ron de Bruin: [Enable or Disable custom Ribbon buttons in Excel 2007 and higher](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win013.htm).